# Question about quantum mechanics and diatomic molecule

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, molecules

> "The double well is a very primitive one-dimensional model for the potential experienced by an electron in a diatomic molecule (the two wells represent the attractive force of the nuclei)"

As found in Griffiths 3rd edition problem 2.47.
And the problem about whether the electron would draw the nuclei together or push them apart?

My question is what makes the electron push the nuclei apart depending on the energy state (ground or 1st excited)? The electric force causes them to get closer not the opposite, as is found in the solution of the problem (in the odd first excited state).

Comment: Can you give the title of Griffiths 3rd edition book?